# Replace the words in String without using String replace

Tags: java, string, eclipse, replace, jar

Is there any solution on how to replace words in string without using String replace?

As you all can see this is like hard coded it. Is there any method to make it dynamically? I heard that there is some library file able to make it dynamically but I am not very sure.

Any expert out there able to give me some solutions? Thank you so much and have a nice day.

```
for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
                // To remove the unwanted words in the query
                test = results.toString();
                String testresults = test.replace("numFound=2,start=0,docs=[","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("numFound=1,start=0,docs=[","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("{","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("SolrDocument","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("numFound=4,start=0,docs=[","");
                testresults = testresults.replace("SolrDocument{", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("content=[", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("id=", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("]}]}", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("]}", "");
                testresults = testresults.replace("}", "");
```

Comment: Use [*regular expression(s)*](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).

Comment: why looping on results if your just doing results.toString() on it ? I don't see i being used. just asking...

Comment: Because basically I am retrieving the info/contents from Solr. But when it display the results, it will show those unwanted words that I replaced. As it is static and I want to make it dynamically.  @Alex

Comment: `testresults = testresults.replaceAll("numFound=\\d+,start=\\d+,docs=[","");` should get you started.

Comment: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps if you showed us what you were *trying* to do, we would be more likely to give you the best solution for you problem.

Comment: *BTW:* If you already did `replace("{","")` and `replace("SolrDocument","")`, what do you expect `replace("SolrDocument{", "")` to do?

Comment: I just wanted to replace the unwanted text in it to make it readable. Because when it print out it is SolrDocument{blahblahblah} I did that to remove SolrDocument{ so it will only display blahblahblah.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you will need learn [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and a built-in String function [String.replaceAll()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to capture all possible unwanted words. 
For example:

```
test.replaceAll("SolrDocument|id=|content=\\[", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply create and use a custom String.replace() method which happens to use the String.replace() method within it:

```
public static String customReplace(String inputString, String replaceWith, String... stringsToReplace) {
    if (inputString.equals("")) { return replaceWith; }
    if (stringsToReplace.length == 0) { return inputString; }

    for (int i = 0; i < stringsToReplace.length; i++) {
        inputString = inputString.replace(stringsToReplace[i], replaceWith);
    }

    return inputString;
}
```

In the example method above you can supply as many strings as you like to be replaced within the **stringsToReplace** parameter as long as they are delimited with a comma (,). They will all be replaced with what you supply for the **replaceWith** parameter.

Here is an example of how it can be used:

```
String test = "This is a string which contains numFound=2,start=0,docs=[ crap and it may also "
            + "have numFound=1,start=0,docs=[ junk in it along with open curly bracket { and "
            + "the SolrDocument word which might also have ]}]} other crap in there too.";

testResult = customReplace(strg, "", "numFound=2,start=0,docs=[ ", "numFound=1,start=0,docs=[ ", 
                         + "{ ", "SolrDocument ", "]}]} ");

System.out.println(testResult);
```

You can also pass a single String Array which contains all your unwanted strings within its elements and pass that array to the **stringsToReplace** parameter, for example:

```
String test = "This is a string which contains numFound=2,start=0,docs=[ crap and it may also "
            + "have numFound=1,start=0,docs=[ junk in it along with open curly bracket { and "
            + "the SolrDocument word which might also have ]}]} other crap in there too.";

String[] unwantedStrings = {"numFound=2,start=0,docs=[ ", "numFound=1,start=0,docs=[ ", 
                            "{ ", "SolrDocument ", "]}]} "};

String testResult = customReplace(test, "", unwantedStrings);

System.out.println(testResult);
```

Comment: Just a question, is this still counted as hard coded? Sorry if my question sound stupid as I am new to programming.

Comment: No it is not considered Hard Coding because you pass a variable consisting the desired string items to replace rather than those string items being placed directly within the source code. The unwantedStrings variable can be filled dynamically by any source you desire, even from contents within a text file.

Comment: Hard Coding refers to the practice of using actual data values (as in actual numbers or strings like 3 or “abcd”) in the source code when instead what should be used are variables that accept any input value.